# This may be odd to some of you (soln to 1st ODE with NO constant of integration)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is to solve the following 1st ODE:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2 + \sqrt{y - 2x + 3}$$

If you use the following substitution
$$u=\sqrt{y-2x+3}$$

to solve the problem, you should end up with a new form of the ODE as followed:

$$u(2\frac{du}{dx}-1)=0$$

This new equation will give you two solutions, among which is 
$$u=0 \Rightarrow \sqrt{y - 2x + 3}=0\Rightarrow y=2x-3$$

The other solution is not of interest.

This simple solution satisfies the ODE nicely but contains no constant of integration. This is however not very practical because in initial value problem this would cause some trouble.

Any thought on the physical meaning of a solution that has no constant of integration, or is it a mere mathematical result?

Thank you!

Comment: The only solution you look at is the term in the brackets. Because the first one (assuming you mean u =0 from the factoring out) can be thought of as a condition (if you require the solution to be so) . Try not to think of it as like finding solutions of a polynomial for example.

Comment: It's hard to think of $y = 2x - 3$ as a condition because it fits the ODE so well. Typically for a generic ODE problem (no initial values or boundary values involved), you will have a general solution or a family of solutions. However in this case, the solution of interest is definite (even though there is another distinct general solution to the ODE) and distinct.

Answer (score 3):

Why is the other solution "not of interest?" The equation you've written implies that either $u=0$ or $\frac{du}{dx}-1=0$. The latter gives $u(x)=x+C$ which implies $\sqrt{y-2x+3}=x+C$, so $y=(x+C)^2+2x-3$.

Here's what's interesting: Notice that the other solution $y=2x-3$ has a zero when $x=3/2$. Yet, plug in $x=3/2$ into the other equation and force $y=0$. This gives: $0=(3/2+C)^2$ giving $C=-3/2$. In other words, if you specify initial condition $y(3/2)=0$, then there are *two* distinct solutions to the ODE. This is not surprising if you are familiar with [uniqueness theory of ODEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). In your case, at $x=3/2$, the function $\sqrt{y}$ is not Lipschitz at $y=0$, hence the solution might not be unique.

Moral: functions that are not Lipchitz at a point will give weird ODE results.

Comment: Actually you lost a factor of $1/4$.  Note that $y = (x + C)^2/4 + 2x - 3$ is a solution for $x \ge -C$.  For $x < -C$ you get the wrong square root.

Comment: By "interest" I mean the non-existence of the constant of integration in the simple solution $y = 2x - 3$ because without the constant it would fail to be the solution if an initial value were given and did not satisfy $y_0 = 2x_0 - 3$. I'm curious if this solution is just a mathematical solution or it has some physical insight into the behavior of the given ODE. Notice that this is not an initial value problem.